# decimales oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

tengo una duda, tengo en base de datos un dato de tipo `number(5,2)`
pero tengo valores con

```
1
1.1
3.18
```

la duda es, en la consulta puedo hacer que se le agregue los ceros a la derecha para que el dato salga

```
1.00
1.10
3.18
```

la base es oracle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alguien hizo una pregunta muy similar [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/53985/reemplazar-formato-de-decimales-en-base-de-datos) y creo que [la respuesta que dejé allí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/54016/18951) te puedes servir también.

Como no puedo marcar esta pregunta como duplicada de aquella, vuelvo a incluír los detalles en esta respuesta:

Lo que entiendo es que estás buscando la forma de formatear números de modo que siempre te queden 2 dígitos después del punto de decimal.

Esto se puede hacer con la función `TO_CHAR` especificando el formato deseado:

```
to_char(num, 'fm9990.00')
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://rextester.com/VPZGD24235)</kbd>

- el `fm` es para eliminar espacios sobrantes.
- Los `9` especifican dígitos opcionales.
- Los `0` especifican dígitos que deben aparecer.

Si los números pueden tener más dígitos que los miles, simplemente agrégale más `9`s a la izquierda.

Ejemplo:

```
to_char(num, 'fm9999999990.00')
```

Comment: si quisiera hacer select de numeros de una tabla que contienen mas de 2 decimales como hará la transformación?